# PHP Error when trying to connect to MySQL Database

Tags: php, mysql, database, ubuntu

I have a problem with a Database Connection. It sounds really simple, but I have been searching for a solution for a while now...

My Server:

- Ubuntu 16.04
- Apache 2
- PHP 7.0.15

I put this PHP script into `/var/www/html` and gave it `chmod 744 / 755` for testing.

```
try {
    $pdo=new PDO ('mysql:dbname=test;host=ip-address', 'user', 'password');
    $pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
} catch(PDOException $e) {
    echo 'Verbindung fehlgeschlagen: ' . $e->getMessage();
}
```

But when I call this file in my browser, the following message shows up:

> SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] Connection refused

The Database User has every rights. I also tried the root user.

Can anyone help me with this one? What could be the problem? I can't find an answer.

Thanks - Flo!

Comment: Restart sql and apache.

Comment: Try: `$pdo=new PDO ('mysql:host=ip-address;dbname=test', 'user', 'password');`

Comment: Is MySQL running, and on the default 3306 port?

Comment: Change for a moment `PDOException` and replace it by `Exception` and tell us what is giving. Apart of that, the error is saying that the Database is rejecting your connection. If you are not in a `localhost` then you must open ports and configuration to allow that. If you are in `localhost`, maybe you have wrong user permissions to that Database. About the rights on the user, you can add rights for any IP or for a fixed IP.

Comment: Do you have phpmyadmin installed and can that connect OK?

Comment: Can you also check PDOException **§e** should be $e

Comment: Is this on a Digital Ocen Droplet or similar VM?

Comment: Thanks for your answers :) I already restarted ubuntu, mysql and apache several times. I also used your PDO statement and changed "PDOException" to "Exception" - the same thing all the time. I have phpmyadmin installed and it works fine. The § is a $, i just missspelled that here. But i am not sure about the port. I have a IPCop running between my WindowsVM (where i call the php) and the ubuntu server. I'll try to open the port now

Comment: If you are not in the same network (**LOCALHOST**) follow [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14779244/1998801) tutorial.

Comment: But i tried to run this script on localhost with w3m, and i got the same error :(

Comment: I already did all of the tutorial stuff. But it doesnt work :/ And if there were any port problems, the script would work on the localhost, but it doesn't

Answer (score 1):

Your code is correct, I have tested it with my database. Only small typo error is there, `catch(PDOException §e)` have the wrong character '§' instead of '$'

Comment: Sorry for that typo. I made this error here, but in the script on the server it is a $

Comment: see by providing port number also, `$pdo = new PDO('mysql:dbname=test;host=ip-address;port=xxxx;', $username, $password);`